# Making a simple search engine php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a following table called `tags` like
`id|tag_title|post_id` and a table `posts` with `id|title`

i am able to search using `fulltext` functionality but that is only restricted to searching the `title` in the `posts` table.
What i want is to search both in `tags` and `posts` table and get best results .
How can i accomplish it...!!!

My query:

```
Select title from posts where Match(title) Against('$search' in boolean mode)
```

Comment: I updated @ragingBull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
SELECT title FROM posts WHERE Match(title) Against('$search' IN boolean mode)
UNION
SELECT title FROM posts INNER JOIN tags ON posts.id = tags.post_id WHERE Match(tag_title) Against('$search' IN boolean mode)
```

If you want something more advanced, check out [Apache Solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/) or Apache Lucence